# Polymorphic behavior involving Java Interface

Tags: java, interface, object-oriented-analysis

```
interface MyInterface {

      public List<String> getNames();
}

class MyClass implements MyInterface {

     @Override
     public List<String> getNames() {
         ... 
         return names;
     }     
     public List<String> getTypes() {
          ...
           return types;
     }
}

class MyClassFactory {

    public MyInterface create() {
        ...
        MyInterface myClass = new MyClass();
        return myClass;
    }
}

public class MyClient {

   MyInterface myClass = myClassFactory.create();
   List<String> types = myClass.getTypes();
}
```

In this code, it complains the last line, "List types = myClass.getTypes();" which says the method is not defined for the class. Why is that? Is this not the right way to use the polymorphic behavior?

Comment: You didn't define `getTypes` in the interface, so it's not visible once you implicitly cast to the interface.

Comment: `myClass` is instance of `MyInterface` so that it can not see `getTypes()` function. You may try to cast it to your class to see it. `List<String> types = ((MyClass) myClass).getTypes();`

Answer (score 2):

> Is this not the right way to use the polymorphic behavior?

This would be a perfect way of programming to interface if you called `getNames()`, a method defined in the interface. However, `getTypes()` is defined only in the class, but not in the interface. The compiler is not allowed to use this information, so it is issuing an error.

You can fix this by adding `getTypes()` to the interface, or changing the compile-time type of `myClass` variable to `MyClass`.

Answer (score 0):

Put "public List getTypes();" in MyInterface.Or in your MyClient class use

```
MyClass myClass = (MyClass) myClassFactory.create();
```

this line instead of `

```
MyInterface myClass = myClassFactory.create();
```